# print error when integer is enter inside a string input

Tags: python-3.x

I want to have a program that print out error messages when an integer or float value is enter into a string input. Example:

```
Enter name: 1234
Invalid name entered. Please enter a new one.

Enter name: Joe
Enter no. phone:123456789
```

(and so on..)

now I only have this:

```
while True:
    try:
        # Note: Python 2.x users should use raw_input, the equivalent of 3.x's input
        age = input("enter name: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid name.")
        continue
    else:
        break
if : 
    print("")
else:
    print("")
```

what do I need to put at the if else?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Very well, so there is only one thing you have to do: write the program :)

Comment: How about something simple like `not mystr[0].isdigit()`?

Comment: or `all(char.isalpha() or char == ' ' for char in mystr)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a string or set (sets are more efficient) of the forbidden characters and then just iterate over the input string and check if the chars aren't in the `forbidden_chars` set. If the string contains a forbidden character, set a flag variable (called `invalid_found` in the example below) to `True` and only break out of the while loop if the flag is `False`, that means if no invalid char was found.

```
forbidden_chars = set('0123456789')

while True:
    inpt = input('Enter a string: ')
    invalid_found = False
    for char in inpt:
        if char in forbidden_chars:
            print('Invalid name.')
            invalid_found = True
            break
    if not invalid_found:
        break

print(inpt)
```

Comment: Also, check out [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). There are people with numbers in their names.

Answer (score 0):

```
isdigit() - it is a string method which checks that whether a string entered is numeric(only numeric, no spaces, or alphabets) or not.
```

```
    while True:
        name = input("Enter your name : ")
        if name.isdigit():
            print("Invalid name please enter only alphabets.")
            continue
        else:
            phone_number = int(input("Enter Your phone number : "))
            print(f"Name : {name}")
            print(f"Phone_number : {phone_number}")
            break
```